# How to bring view in front of everything?

Tags: android, animation, button, textview, z-order

I have activity and a lot of widgets on it, some of them have animations and because of the animations some of the widgets are moving (translating) one over another. For example the text view is moving over some buttons . . .

Now the thing is I want the buttons to be always on the front. And when the textview is moving I want to move behind the buttons.

I can not achieve this I tried everything I know, and "bringToFront()" definitelly doesn't work.

note I do not want to control  the z-order by the order of placing element to layout cause I simply can't :), the layout is complex and I can not place all the buttons at the begging of the layout

Comment: I used a `RelativeLayout` with the "top" view appearing last in the XML. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31340762/1121497

Comment: can anyone please tell corresponding code in xml of 'bringToFront'

Comment: Try using elevation bottomView=elevation:1dp and topView=elevation:2dp in your xml || ViewCompat.setElevation(View, int)

Answer (score 169):

You can call bringToFront() on the view you want to get in the front

This is an example:

```
    yourView.bringToFront();
```

Comment: Unexpected result: I used that in a vertical linear layout and the view bringed to front appeared at the bottom... For example, I had `A / B / C` and wanted to bring `A` to front, so after running `a.bringToFront()` I ended up with a layout like `B / C / A`.

Comment: So I found `LinearLayout` can't be used with `bringToFront`. I ended up using a `RelativeLayout`. See my comment on the question itself.

Comment: can anyone please tell corresponding code in xml of 'bringToFront'

Comment: This results in re-positioning of the element I'm moving to the front for whatever reason. `ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(view, 1)` works perfectly on the other hand.

Comment: if I used in manifest android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" in activity than yourView.bringToFront(); works perfectly, but I used 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" yourView.bringToFront(); doesn't work. Any clue on that one.

Comment: I am trying to temporarily disable all buttons. I put an overlay view when `bringToFront()` on the overlay view works for disabling but how to `bringToBack()` after in order to re-enable them?

Comment: Does not work for me

Answer (score 89):

With this code in xml

```
 android:translationZ="90dp"
```

Comment: Where did `90dp` come from?

Comment: it is manual entry. You can try with based on your requirement. either 45dp or 135dp or 180dp or 270dp

Comment: Couldn't you just use 1dp ?

Comment: required API 21+

Comment: translationZ value (90dp) is added to the value provided for android:elevation. So, translationZ + elevation will decide the order. The view with the highest sum will be in the front. The next highest behind it and so on.

Answer (score 55):

I've been looking through stack overflow to find a good answer and when i couldn't find one i went looking through the docs.

no one seems to have stumbled on this simple answer yet:

```
ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(view, translationZ);
```

default translation z is 0.0

Comment: That is the position of the element on the Z-axis in px, also known as elevation. setTranslationX would move the view along the X-axis (left/right), setTranslationY along the Y-axis (top/bottom). The Z-axis is the 3rd axis.

Comment: What about `setZ()`? If I recall correctly, the Z position of the view is its elevation plus its translation Z, after all.

Comment: @Gensoukyou1337, then                         `ViewCompat.setZ(view, yourValueInPixels);`

`view.setZ()` works only on API 21 and higher.

Comment: Checked Java 8 code in Android Studio - it only checks if SDK_INT >= 21, so for <21 api it has no effect.

Answer (score 45):

An even simpler solution is to edit the XML of the activity. Use

```
android:translationZ=""
```

Comment: This is only useful in Android API 21 or above.

Answer (score 26):

`bringToFront()` is the right way, but, NOTE that you must call `bringToFront()` and `invalidate()` method on highest-level view (under your root view), for e.g.:

Your view's hierarchy is:

```
-RelativeLayout
|--LinearLayout1
|------Button1
|------Button2
|------Button3
|--ImageView
|--LinearLayout2
|------Button4
|------Button5
|------Button6
```

So, when you animate back your buttons (1->6), your buttons will under (below) the `ImageView`. To bring it over (above) the `ImageView` you must call `bringToFront()` and `invalidate()` method on your `LinearLayout`s. Then it will work :)
**NOTE: Remember to set `android:clipChildren="false"` for your root layout or animate-view's gradparent_layout. Let's take a look at my real code:

.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:hw="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/common_theme_color"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.binh.helloworld.customviews.HWActionBar
        android:id="@+id/action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_actionbar_height"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        hw:titleText="@string/app_name" >
    </com.binh.helloworld.customviews.HWActionBar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/action_bar"
        android:clipChildren="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgv_main"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/common_imgv_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/common_imgv_height"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Some code in .java

```
private LinearLayout layoutTop, layoutBottom;
...
layoutTop = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_top);
layoutBottom = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_bottom);
...
//when animate back
//dragedView is my layoutTop's child view (i added programmatically) (like buttons in above example) 
dragedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
layoutTop.bringToFront();
layoutTop.invalidate();
dragedView.startAnimation(animation); // TranslateAnimation
dragedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

GLuck!

Comment: what if you only want to bring button 6 above the imageview and not the other buttons?

Comment: @AdamKatz: I think you must re-organize them into another level fist. Then, bring it in your way.

Comment: thanks I am trying to bring just one item of a recycler view above a view but leave the other items below it, pretty stuck!

Comment: I used the same. Its working fine with a single problem that it hides the toolbar.

Comment: Does this work with multiple levels? Let's say I have a `ConstraintLayout` that contains a `RelativeLayout`, and another `RelativeLayout`, both are the same size as its root `ConstraintLayout` (`match_parent`). The first `RelativeLayout` has a `Button`, and is also behind (z-order-wise) the second `RelativeLayout`. Can I make the `Button` in the first `RelativeLayout` to appear as if it were on top of everything, such that it's visible and clickable, using `View::bringToFront()`?

Answer (score 20):

If you are using `ConstraintLayout`, just put the element after the other elements to make it on front than the others

Comment: what would be the programmatic approach?

Answer (score 18):

Try `FrameLayout`, it gives you the possibility to put views one above another. You can create two `LinearLayouts`: one with the background views, and one with foreground views, and combine them using the `FrameLayout`. Hope this helps.

Comment: How can we bring it to top just like a dialog ?

Comment: @Infinity, You can create a FragmentDialog for this purpose, or just use the Theme.Dialog for your Activity.

Comment: I can't use FragmentDialog since its incompatible for API 10. Secondly, I'm already using a theme for my application. Is there any other way ? I've used it FrameLayout just like you said !

Comment: @Infinity, You can use compatibility library version of FragmentDialog, which is available from API 4.

Answer (score 6):

i have faced the same problem.
the following solution have worked for me.

```
 FrameLayout glFrame=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.animatedView);
        glFrame.addView(yourView);
        glFrame.bringToFront();
        glFrame.invalidate();
```

2nd solution is by using xml adding this attribute to the view xml

```
android:translationZ=""
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use the `bringChildToFront`, you can check if this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#bringChildToFront(android.view.View)) is helpful in the [Android Developers page](https://developer.android.com/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

There can be another way which saves the day. Just init a new Dialog with desired layout and just show it. I need it for showing a loadingView over a DialogFragment and this was the only way I succeed.

```
Dialog topDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
topDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_top);
topDialog.show();
```

bringToFront() might not work in some cases like mine. But content of dialog_top layout must override anything on the ui layer. But anyway, this is an ugly workaround.

Answer (score 3):

You can use BindingAdapter like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("bringToFront")
public static void bringToFront(View view, Boolean flag) {
    if (flag) {
        view.bringToFront();
    }
}


  <ImageView
        ...
        app:bringToFront="@{true}"/>
```

Comment: where should the bindingadapter code go?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `elevation` attribute if your minimum api level is 21. And you can reorder view to the bottom of other views to bring it to front. But if elevation of other views is higher, they will be on top of your view.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the overlapping views really depends of 4 things:

1. The attribute `android:elevation` which is measured in dp/sp
2. The attribute `android:translationZ` which is also measured in dp/sp.
3. In Constraint Layout, the order in which you put the views in your Component Tree is also the order to be shown.
4. The programmatically order that you set through methods like `view.bringToFront()` in your kotlin/java code.

The numerals 1 and 2 compite with each other and take preference over the points 3 and  4: if you set `elevation="4dp"` for View 1 and `translationZ="2dp"` for View 2, View 1 will always be on top regardless of the numerals 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Stack [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2136812/lena-bru) over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25311493/3233722) explanation, I've got this working even on Android 4.1.1

```
((View)myView.getParent()).requestLayout();
myView.bringToFront();
```

On my dynamic use, for example, I did

```
public void onMyClick(View v)
     {
     ((View)v.getParent()).requestLayout();
     v.bringToFront();
     }
```

And Bamm !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `LinearLayout` you should call `myView.bringToFront()` and after you should call `parentView.requestLayout()` and `parentView.invalidate()` to force the parent to redraw with the new child order.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange them in the order you wants to show. Suppose, you wanna show view 1 on top of view 2. Then write view 2 code then write view 1 code. If you cant does this ordering, then call bringToFront() to the root view of the layout you wants to bring in front.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use framelayout. And the better way to do this is to make the view invisible when thay are not require. Also you need to set the position for each and every view,So that they will move according to there corresponding position

Comment: Invisibilty is different thing from Z order. This answer is not correct solution..

Answer (score -37):

You can set visibility to false of other views.

```
view1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
...
```

or

```
view1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
view2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
...
```

and set

```
viewN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I need that all to be visible, that is not the problem, the problem is the z-order. if viability was the problem it would be to easy to solve . . .