# android - linear layout bringToFront()

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have 4 buttons in my linear layout and i need to bring to front first button.

Normal order is

```
    Button 1 | Button 2 | Button 3 | Button 4
```

But when I call `button1.bringToFront()` function , `button1` is going to end like

```
    Button 2 | Button 3 | Button 4 | Button 1
```

How can I solve this problem. Relative layout doesn't causes this problem but I have to use `LinearLayout` because buttons will order vertically and I'm deleting a button in some conditions.

Thanks

Comment: what output you are looking for ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`LinearLayout` doesn't work with the z-axis, hence, it's name `linear`. Try using a `RelativeLayout` and then call `bringToFront()` to get the desired effect. With a `RelativeLayout` you can call `layout_alignBollow` to order the views vertically. Or you can nest views and layouts, for instance, within your `LinearLayout` nest three `RelativeLayout` within those you can place your `Buttons` (be careful with this approach as adding too many views can be a bad thing).

Comment: What is layout_alignBollow ?

Comment: I had a row of overlapping buttons. Your tip of using a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout worked for me (in combination with calling requestLayout() and invalidate() on that RelativeLayout (it being the parent of the overlapping buttons).

Answer (score 2):

If you have to work with z-axis in a LinearLayout, you may use setTranslationZ function.

Example:

```
yourView.setTranslationZ(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

make your layout call the `forceLayout()` to disable re-arrangement of the layout.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Since `bringToFront` messes up the `LinearLayout` order, I decided to use a `RelativeLayout` and put the "top" view (the view I want on top) last in the XML.

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

    <ViewBelow
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_on_top"
        ...
        />

    <!-- Last view in XML appears above other views on screen -->
    <ViewOnTop
        android:id="@+id/view_on_top"
        ...
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the specific case of this question, the `ViewOnTop` would be the Button 1, and the `ViewBelow` would be a `LinearLayout` containing the other buttons.