# Android - Onclick Image bring front of text

Tags: android

How to Onclick Image bring front of text?

I have a layout and i use imageView1.bringToFront(); in button onclick event but not working!

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="247dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Frame Demo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and MainActivity

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            imageView1.bringToFront();
        }
    });
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306180/view-bring-to-front-doesnt-work

Comment: because i want get back @mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO this :boolean isclicked=true;

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if(isClicked){
         firstClick();
        isClicked=false
    }else{
     secondClick();
      isClicked=true;
       }
        }

      firstClick(){
      ((View)Imageview.getParent()).requestLayout();
        Imageview.bringChildToFront(this);}
        });
       }

     secondClick(){
   ///Do Your code
 }
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: imageView1.bringToFront(); working but i can't get back when i click button againt.

Comment: okay so problem you are having is next click: you can use any boolean value to denote  first click and second click. i am editing my answer have a look

Answer (score 0):

simple `setVisibility(View.GONE)` of `TextView`

Comment: but i want get back it so i can't use this method hix

Comment: when you want that `TextView` again then set its `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`