# android bring to front not working on card view

Tags: java, android, cardview, bringtofront

In android `bringToFront()` not working when trying to bring a view to the front of a card view. It seems that the card view always has a higher priority than other views. I try `requestLayout()` plus `bringToFront()` too but it doesn't work. Is there any idea on how to solve this problem? I tried to use `elevation` but it does not work on android below API level 21.

```
view.post(() -> {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view.bringToFront();
    view.requestLayout();
});
```

Comment: Please try this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306180/view-bring-to-front-doesnt-work

Comment: @Prateek i tried this too but does not work. it cant came to front of a  cardView

Comment: try `view.requestFocus()` before `view.bringToFront();`

Comment: @Zain i try your solution but doesn't work either

Comment: @Prateek  finally i found the solution. putting the cardView in a FrameLayout. when parent of each cardView is a FrameLayout then this methods works but without a FrameLayout the card view always has a higher elevation

Answer (score 1):

finally the solution was using FrameLayout. if anyone wants to load a view in front of a cardView it must put cardView in a frameLayout. without frameLayout cardView always get a higher elevation and translation in show

Comment: if anyone found a better solution please inform here to know.