# XML alternative for translationZ in API level that is less than 21

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293115/what-is-the-alternative-for-translationz-in-lower-api-level-less-than-21) demonstrates how to programmatically set the `translationZ` attribute for a view using: `ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(view, translationZ);` in an API level that is less than 21.

Is there a way to do this in XML only with an `AppCompatImageView` or is it only possible programatically?

My `AppCompatImageView` is inside of a `ConstraintLayout`