# Android: How to bring layout in front of a dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, android-progressbar

I want to create a `constraintLayout` with a circle `progressBar` in front of a dialog. And it used for a loading screen and lock every action while loading.
But i cannot find anyway to do that.

I searched on Google but cannot find a working solution..

[searching_1](https://reformatcode.com/code/android/android-bring-view-to-the-front-of-a-dialog)

[searching_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759279/how-to-bring-view-on-front-of-everything)

I tried:

```
layoutTop.bringToFront();
layoutTop.invalidate();
```

and I put these code more that once in my activity.
But the dialog is always on top of my `constraintLayout`.

I used to use `ProgressDialog` which is cool and can show on top of everything easily. But it deprecated in `API` lv. 26.

Is there other simple method to bring layout in front of a dialog?

Thanks so much of any help!

Comment: why don't you use your own custom dialog which can extend alert dialog ? in this way you can use it as a progress dialog too and it is also not deprecated ;)

Comment: implement your progressbar on your dialog

Comment: I have many button on my page. Each button will create one dialog programmatically. If I implement the progressbar inside my dialog, I need to input the code in maybe 20 dialog. It can do the job but if possible I want to handle the loading layout in the parent layout