# NavigationDrawer behind SmartGLView

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, navigation-drawer

I have an activity contains a `NavigationDrawer` and `SmartGLView`.

`SmartGLView` is inside `DrawerLayout`.

When `NavigationDrawer` show up, some part of it was covered by `SmartGLView`. How can I make `NavigationDrawer` on top of `SmartGLView`?

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/pl_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/pl_nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pl_tv_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="line1"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pl_tv_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/normal"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pl_tv_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/defaultTime"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pl_tv_speed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/defaultSpeed"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/pl_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <fr.arnaudguyon.smartgl.opengl.SmartGLView
                android:id="@+id/smartGLView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Try to move NavigationView to the bottom.

Comment: After move NavigationView to the bottom, it works correctly in the emulator, but not in my phone. In my phone, I still can't see the part cover by SmartGLView, but I can click items in the menu.

Comment: I have try different emulators, Pixel API 27 and API 22 works, Nexus S API 22 not works.

Answer (score 0):

Move navigation view to the bottom.

The main content view (the first FrameLayout above) must be the first child in the DrawerLayout because the XML order implies z-ordering and the drawer must be on top of the content.

Comment: After move NavigationView to the bottom, it works correctly in the emulator, but not in my phone. In my phone, I still can't see the part cover by SmartGLView, but I can click items in the menu.

Comment: What version of the Android is on your phone?

Comment: Version of Android on my phone is Android 7.0

Comment: Try to call bringToFront() on the navigation view. Or ViewCompat.setTranslationZ. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759279/how-to-bring-view-on-front-of-everything