# Make constraint layout untouchable

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-constraintlayout

I have two layouts, manageLayout and mainLayout. They have constraints to the parent on all sides. I need in a one time have manageLayout on the top of mainLayout, and on the other time mainLayout on the top of manageLayout. Of course, there is sense in using visibility=gone on one of them, but i need one layout on the background of another. Problem: layout on the background handle events from top layout. How to make lower layout(and his elements) untouchable when another layout is risen?
Layout tree image:
[LayoutTreeImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyUJQ.png)
Code sample, where i want to disable communications with lower layout: https://pastebin.com/PeL7u3YD (not only `isSaveEnabled=false` had no effect, also `isEnabled=false` had no effects too)

Comment: Can you provide relevant source code? Any chance this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34391262?

Comment: Added layout tree to post, i don't understand, for what i need paste code - all the problem described in the post.

Comment: This answer is about how to make one layout in the top of other. I have already done with it using `visibility=gone\visible`, but I am still able to communicate with lower layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need an explanation.

Once you've initialized both your views for `mainLayout` and `manageLayout`, you will need to set an empty `onClickListener` on both of them. Basically, layouts should get the click but do nothing. This way you can block the layout and widgets underneath the view on Front from getting clicked.

Now for for switching view to front maintain a boolean to know which view is on the front and on your button click set the other view [`bringToFront()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#bringToFront()) (Or try some other ways mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759279/how-to-bring-view-on-front-of-everything) if you want) and don't forget to switch the boolean value.

Let me know if this works for you or you have any issues regarding this.

Comment: I think, it can be replace by setting `isClickable=false` to lower layout, but it had no effect - i am able to communicate with lower layout. Let me bring some remarks to answer - i bring layout to the top of other using `visibility=gone` or `visibility=visible` to manageLayout.

Comment: The view placed on top must intercept the views on the lower one. That is the reason you need a clickListener on the view onFront. If you replace that lower layout will get the click, is that what you meant?

Comment: I need for lower layout NOT get top layout's clicks

Comment: With regards to your question "How to make lower layout(and his elements) untouchable when another layout is risen?" is what I am trying to say, if your "risen layout" covers the whole screen as you mentioned you just need to set a click listener on that "risen layout" so that clicking prevents all clicks on lower layout.

Answer (score 0):

According to my perception, you can make lower layout `setEnable(false)`. I hope it will work.

Comment: I done what you told me, but it doesn't work - i am able to touch and communicate with lower layout, despite disabling it

Comment: Can you provide your code for a little bit of idea?

Comment: There you can see my function for getting one layout to the top of another: (https://pastebin.com/PeL7u3YD)

Comment: That page has been removed.

Comment: Try to do setenable(false) with all the elements of lower layout.

Comment: It is truly hard because of recyclerView on lower layout